# Computer wakes up from hibernation at exctly 3:40am every day

Tags: windows-8, sleep, hibernate, tasks, wake-up

I'm getting tired of waking up to my computer being turned on, and event log shows that it's waking up everyday at 3:40am and most times won't go back to sleep after the determined 30 minutes (maybe from being in the lock screen?).
There are no devices armed for wake, activation timers are disabled and all wake options disabled in the BIOS and energy star 4.0c is enabled (was disabled before but no difference).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was the dreaded Windows Media Center update task, which for some reason wakes my computer even with Wake Timers set to disabled on the power options.

There is even a Microsoft KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979878

Answer (score 0):

Is Windows Update set to install new updates every day at that time on your machine? Open Windows Update and then click on Change settings to check.

Comment: I was checking my Task Scheduler the other day and noticed lots of Tasks scheduled at around 3:00am each day.

Comment: Windows Update is set for 8pm, and activation timers are disabled.